# How to restore '/usr/lib/gcc/*'

Tags: 16.04, gcc, restore, undelete

On Ubuntu 16.04, I accidentally deleted my `/usr/lib/gcc` dir. I tried to reinstall `gcc` but the dir won't be created again. How do I restore.

```
~$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc
gcc-5-base:amd64, libgcc-5-dev:amd64, cpp-5, gcc-5, gcc-6-base:amd64: /usr/lib/gcc
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc`

Comment: `~$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc`
`gcc-5-base:amd64, libgcc-5-dev:amd64, cpp-5, gcc-5, gcc-6-base:amd64: /usr/lib/gcc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to reinstall all packages on your system that are known to have files in the deleted `/usr/lib/gcc` directory.

The output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc` told us which packages this are, in your case:

```
gcc-5-base:amd64, libgcc-5-dev:amd64, cpp-5, gcc-5, gcc-6-base:amd64
```

Now let's reinstall all of them:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-5-base:amd64 libgcc-5-dev:amd64 cpp-5 gcc-5 gcc-6-base:amd64
```

---

You can alternatively automate this process and leave the parsing of the package list to `sed`.
That way you only have to run this single command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc | sed 's/,\|: .*//g')
```